# Websocket JSR-356 fail with Jetty 9.4.1

Tags: websocket, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, jsr356

My current web server is embedded Jetty 9.1.5. It works well with JSR-356 to create websocket. These days, I am trying to upgrade to Jetty 9.4.1. Everything works nicely except websocket.
My code like below:

1. Embedded Jetty and Websocket libs:

> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
>    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
>    <version>9.4.1.v20170120</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
>    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
>    <version>9.4.1.v20170120</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
>    <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
>    <version>9.4.1.v20170120</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
>    <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
>    <version>9.4.1.v20170120</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Server endpoint:

> ```
>   @ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/communication/{officeId}/{username}/{oldWSSession}")
>   class WSCommunication {
>      // @OnOpen, @OnMessage, @OnClose methods
>   }
> ```

3. Jetty server, Webapp context, Websocket configuration:

   > ```
   >   // Jetty server
   >   Server server = new Server();
   >   String[] configFiles = {"./etc/jetty.xml"};
   >   for (String configFile : configFiles) {
   >      XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(new File(configFile).toURI().toURL());
   >      configuration.configure(server);
   >
   >      Connector[] connectors =  server.getConnectors();
   >      if (connectors != null && connectors.length == 2) {
   >         ServerConnector serverConnector = (ServerConnector) connectors[1];
   >         serverConnector.setPort(8443);
   >      }
   >    }
   >
   >    // Webapp context
   >    WebAppContext webContext = new WebAppContext(ResourceManager.getWebappsPath(), "/myContext");
   >    webContext.setContextPath("/myContext");
   >    webContext.setResourceBase(ResourceManager.getWebappsPath() + contextPath);
   >    webContext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false");
   >
   >    private List<WebAppContext> listWebContext = new ArrayList<>();
   >    listWebContext.add(webContext);
   >
   >    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
   >    contexts.setHandlers(listWebContext.toArray(new WebAppContext[listWebContext.size()]));
   >    server.setHandler(contexts);
   >
   >    // Start server
   >    server.start();
   >
   >    // Websocket
   >    ServerContainer container =
   >    WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(webContext);
   >    container.addEndpoint(webContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(
   >                          "com.example.WSCommunication"));
   >
   >    container.setDefaultMaxSessionIdleTimeout(84600);
   >
   >    // Dump server log
   >    server.dumpStdErr();
   > ```
4. Dump:

   > ```
   >  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@5ca13457 - STARTED
   >        += qtp348159759{STARTED,10<=19<=200,i=1,q=0} - STARTED
   >        |   +- 30 qtp348159759-30 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
   >   |   +- 31 qtp348159759-31-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
   >        |   +- 89 qtp348159759-89-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
   >        |   +- 85 qtp348159759-85-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
   >        |   +- 33 qtp348159759-33-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
   >        |   +- 36 qtp348159759-36 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
   >   |   +- 35 qtp348159759-35-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
   >        |   +- 90 qtp348159759-90-acceptor-0@6a934d20-ServerConnector@31de14e{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) prio=3
   >        |   +- 84 qtp348159759-84 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
   >   |   +- 86 qtp348159759-86 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
   >   |   +- 38 qtp348159759-38-acceptor-0@21398b5e-ServerConnector@52bab8e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) prio=3
   >        |   +- 87 qtp348159759-87-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
   >        |   +- 92 qtp348159759-92 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
   >        |   +- 32 qtp348159759-32 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
   >   |   +- 34 qtp348159759-34 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
   >   |   +- 88 qtp348159759-88 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
   >   |   +- 39 qtp348159759-39 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
   >   |   +- 37 qtp348159759-37-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
   >        |   +- 83 qtp348159759-83-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
   >        |   +- jobs
   >        += org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@1ca4b0fd - STARTED
   >        |   +- sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
   >        |   +- java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
   >        |   +- java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
   >        |   +- java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
   >        |   +- java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
   >        |   +- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
   >        |   +- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
   >        |   +- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   >        |   +- java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   >        += ServerConnector@52bab8e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
   >        |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@5ca13457 - STARTED
   >        |   +~ qtp348159759{STARTED,10<=19<=200,i=1,q=0} - STARTED
   >        |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@1ca4b0fd - STARTED
   >        |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@4f751fc9
   >        |   += HttpConnectionFactory@30bf9c09[HTTP/1.1] - STARTED
   >        |   |   +- HttpConfiguration@248e9950{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:8443,[]}
   >        |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@282048ea - STARTED
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@65c05e53 id=0 keys=0 selected=0 id=0
   >        |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@6724bccb keys=0
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@1fa04d47 id=1 keys=0 selected=0 id=1
   >        |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@5fcb5753 keys=0
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@7999a7f0 id=2 keys=0 selected=0 id=2
   >        |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3abe8266 keys=0
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@6d2e80a1 id=3 keys=0 selected=0 id=3
   >        |   |       +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@2e5f2aae keys=0
   >        |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080]
   >        |   +- qtp348159759-38-acceptor-0@21398b5e-ServerConnector@52bab8e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
   >        += ServerConnector@31de14e{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443} - STARTED
   >        |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@5ca13457 - STARTED
   >        |   +~ qtp348159759{STARTED,10<=20<=200,i=2,q=0} - STARTED
   >        |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@1ca4b0fd - STARTED
   >        |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@3838889e
   >        |   += SslConnectionFactory@7b040213{SSL->http/1.1} - STARTED
   >        |   |   += SslContextFactory@a3ac71d(file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/conf/iDS.keystore,null) trustAll=false
   >        |   |       +- Protocol Selections
   >        |   |       |   +- Enabled (size=3)
   >        |   |       |   |   +- TLSv1
   >        |   |       |   |   +- TLSv1.1
   >        |   |       |   |   +- TLSv1.2
   >        |   |       |   +- Disabled (size=2)
   >        |   |       |       +- SSLv2Hello - ConfigExcluded:'SSLv2Hello'
   >        |   |       |       +- SSLv3 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'SSLv3'
   >        |   |       +- Cipher Suite Selections
   >        |   |           +- Enabled (size=43)
   >        |   |           |   [CIPHERS]
   >        |   |           +- Disabled (size=39)
   >        |   |               [CIPHERS]
   >        |   += HttpConnectionFactory@116d58cf[HTTP/1.1] - STARTED
   >        |   |   +- HttpConfiguration@3ba7eaf0{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:8443,[SecureRequestCustomizer@229efbd3]}
   >        |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@14690caf - STARTED
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@e1ecb28 id=0 keys=0 selected=0 id=0
   >        |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@2edda3f6 keys=0
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@aea4071 id=1 keys=0 selected=0 id=1
   >        |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@2482929a keys=0
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@5fff729c id=2 keys=0 selected=0 id=2
   >        |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@7f0a5bb3 keys=0
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@32f11b8 id=3 keys=0 selected=0 id=3
   >        |   |       +- sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@153f56b1 keys=0
   >        |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8443]
   >        |   +- qtp348159759-90-acceptor-0@6a934d20-ServerConnector@31de14e{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443}
   >        += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@7b10dd7e[o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e778e26{/myContext,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/myContext/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps}, o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2974d7ef{/myContext_persistent,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data/my_persistent/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data}] - STARTED
   >        |   += o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e778e26{/myContext,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/myContext/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps} - STARTED
   >        |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler589427621==dftMaxIdleSec=1800 - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@76e1ecf - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultAuthenticatorFactory@7cb77d4b
   >        |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@1b1b48e - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@2da1d3c6 - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@5ace38db - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += default@5c13d641==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- aliases=false
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- dirAllowed=true
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCacheSize=256000000
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFileSize=200000000
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- welcomeServlets=false
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- useFileMappedBuffer=true
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- acceptRanges=true
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- etags=false
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFiles=2048
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- redirectWelcome=false
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += jsp@19c47==org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- fork=false
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- compilerSourceVM=1.7
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- logVerbosityLevel=DEBUG
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- compilerTargetVM=1.7
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- scratchdir=/private/var/folders/8p/f__1hb6j0p5bq7ljqdkjg35h0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-myContext-_myContext-any-6227228818832412481.dir/jsp
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- xpoweredBy=false
   >        |   |   |   |   |   +- [/]=>default
   >        |   |   |   |   |   +- [*.jsp, *.jspf, *.jspx, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPF, *.JSPX, *.XSP]=>jsp
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@1dd44bec - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@114d991c - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += ISSSecurityFilter - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += GzipFilter - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- mimeTypes=text/plain,text/html,text/css,application/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/json
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += Dashboard@38fd0a74==com.example.web.Dashboard,jsp=null,order=1,inst=true - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   |   +- parameter=value
   >        |   |   |   |   |   += idental-mvc@441f8928==org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   [SERVLET MAPPING]
   >        |   |   |   |   |   +~ Jetty_WebSocketUpgradeFilter - STARTED
   >        |   |   |   |   |   +- [/*]/[]==1=>Jetty_WebSocketUpgradeFilter
   >   |   |   |   |   |
   >   |   |   |   |   +> null
   >   |   |   |   |   +> null
   >   |   |   |   |   +> null
   >   |   |   |   |   +> []
   >   |   |   |   |   +> /*={*={RoleInfo[],Confidential}}
   >   |   |   |   |   +> /={TRACE={RoleInfo,F,C[],None}, TRACE.omission={RoleInfo[],None}}
   >   |   |   |   +~ com.example.web.ContextListener@32d15710
   >   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionCache@19f2b971[evict=-1,removeUnloadable=false,saveOnCreate=false,saveOnInactiveEvict=false] - STARTED
   >   |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.NullSessionDataStore@26c61a88[passivating=false,graceSec=3600] - STARTED
   >   |   |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager@5bbef235[worker=node0] - STARTED
   >   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@636f4785 - STARTED
   >   |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.ServerContainer@6fda53a8 - STOPPED
   >   |   |   |
   >   |   |   +> WebAppClassLoader=myContext@27e16098
   >   |   |   |   [LIBS]
   >   |   |   |   +- sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
   >   |   |   +> Systemclasses o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e778e26{/myContext,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/myContext/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps}
   >   |   |   |   +- java.
   >   |   |   |   +- javax.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.PushCacheFilter
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.PushSessionCacheFilter
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.w3c.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.xml.
   >   |   |   +> Serverclasses o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e778e26{/myContext,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/myContext/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps}
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.apache.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionData
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.NoJspServlet
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.
   >   |   |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jdt.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.
   >   |   |   |   +- org.objectweb.asm.
   >   |   |   +> Configurations o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e778e26{/myContext,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/myContext/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps}
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration@795e1681
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration@55dd7cc5
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration@4c174a94
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration@71ed07ad
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration@780efd0f
   >   |   |   +> Handler attributes o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e778e26{/myContext,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/myContext/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps}
   >   |   |   |   +- javax.servlet.context.tempdir=/private/var/folders/8p/f__1hb6j0p5bq7ljqdkjg35h0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-myContext-_myContext-any-6227228818832412481.dir
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.SCI=WebSocketUpgradeFilter[configuration=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.NativeWebSocketConfiguration@468b9d9f]
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.Executor=qtp348159759{STARTED,10<=20<=200,i=2,q=0}
   >   |   |   |   +- org.apache.catalina.jsp_classpath=[LIBS]
   >   |   |   |   +- javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.ServerContainer@6fda53a8
   >   |   |   +> Context attributes o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e778e26{/myContext,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/myContext/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps}
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory=org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory[decorators=1]
   >   |   |   |   +- com.sun.jsp.tagFileJarUrlsCache={}
   >   |   |   |   +- org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextScope=org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextScope@30be2c30
   >   |   |   |   +- org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT=Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Mar 02 22:05:59 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
   >   |   |   |   +- resourceCache=ResourceCache[null,org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@297785e5]@647951169
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.NativeWebSocketConfiguration=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.NativeWebSocketConfiguration@468b9d9f
   >   |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter=WebSocketUpgradeFilter[configuration=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.NativeWebSocketConfiguration@468b9d9f]
   >   |   |   |   +- com.sun.jsp.taglibraryCache={}
   >   |   |   +> Initparams o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e778e26{/myContext,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps/myContext/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/webapps}
   >   |   |       +- contextConfigLocation=classpath:applicationContext.xml
   >   |   |       +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed=false
   >   |   += o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2974d7ef{/myContext_persistent,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data/my_persistent/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data} - STARTED
   >   |       += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler1013179752==dftMaxIdleSec=1800 - STARTED
   >   |       |   += org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@7dfd9178 - STARTED
   >   |       |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultAuthenticatorFactory@68b06b8f
   >   |       |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@39e59923 - STARTED
   >   |       |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@1a8e73d2 - STARTED
   >   |       |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@b6957aa - STARTED
   >   |       |   |   |   += default@5c13d641==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- aliases=false
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- dirAllowed=true
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- maxCacheSize=256000000
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFileSize=200000000
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- welcomeServlets=false
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- useFileMappedBuffer=true
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- acceptRanges=true
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- etags=false
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFiles=2048
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- redirectWelcome=false
   >   |       |   |   |   += jsp@19c47==org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- fork=false
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- compilerSourceVM=1.7
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- logVerbosityLevel=DEBUG
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- compilerTargetVM=1.7
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- scratchdir=/private/var/folders/8p/f__1hb6j0p5bq7ljqdkjg35h0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-my_persistent-_myContext_persistent-any-707911495794918084.dir/jsp
   >   |       |   |   |   |   +- xpoweredBy=false
   >   |       |   |   |   +- [/]=>default
   >   |       |   |   |   +- [*.jsp, *.jspf, *.jspx, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPF, *.JSPX, *.XSP]=>jsp
   >   |       |   |   |
   >   |       |   |   +> null
   >   |       |   |   +> null
   >   |       |   |   +> null
   >   |       |   |   +> []
   >   |       |   |   +> /={TRACE={RoleInfo,F,C[],None}, TRACE.omission={RoleInfo[],None}}
   >   |       |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionCache@606eb95b[evict=-1,removeUnloadable=false,saveOnCreate=false,saveOnInactiveEvict=false] - STARTED
   >   |       |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.NullSessionDataStore@755718f4[passivating=false,graceSec=3600] - STARTED
   >   |       |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager@5bbef235[worker=node0] - STARTED
   >   |       += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@1c2ee56f - STARTED
   >   |       |
   >   |       +> WebAppClassLoader=1053927516@3ed1a85c
   >   |       |   +- sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
   >   |       +> Systemclasses o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2974d7ef{/myContext_persistent,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data/my_persistent/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data}
   >   |       |   +- java.
   >   |       |   +- javax.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.PushCacheFilter
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.PushSessionCacheFilter
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.
   >   |       |   +- org.w3c.
   >   |       |   +- org.xml.
   >   |       +> Serverclasses o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2974d7ef{/myContext_persistent,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data/my_persistent/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data}
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.apache.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionData
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.NoJspServlet
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.
   >   |       |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jdt.
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.
   >   |       |   +- org.objectweb.asm.
   >   |       +> Configurations o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2974d7ef{/myContext_persistent,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data/my_persistent/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data}
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration@5d3b3547
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration@488aebda
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration@5d7da87
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration@6eb942cf
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration@6a2cd352
   >   |       +> Handler attributes o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2974d7ef{/myContext_persistent,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data/my_persistent/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data}
   >   |       |   +- javax.servlet.context.tempdir=/private/var/folders/8p/f__1hb6j0p5bq7ljqdkjg35h0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-my_persistent-_myContext_persistent-any-707911495794918084.dir
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.Executor=qtp348159759{STARTED,10<=20<=200,i=2,q=0}
   >   |       +> Context attributes o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2974d7ef{/myContext_persistent,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data/my_persistent/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data}
   >   |       |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory=org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory[decorators=1]
   >   |       |   +- com.sun.jsp.tagFileJarUrlsCache={}
   >   |       |   +- resourceCache=ResourceCache[null,org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@756731f6]@1323290175
   >   |       |   +- com.sun.jsp.taglibraryCache={}
   >   |       +> Initparams o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2974d7ef{/myContext_persistent,file:///workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data/my_persistent/,AVAILABLE}{/workspace/myApp/myApp-server/data}
   >   |           +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed=false
   >   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@6ad45211 - STARTED
   >   +- {}
   >   +- {}
   >   +- {}
   >   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager@5bbef235[worker=node0] - STARTED
   >   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper@666eba5a[interval=600000, ownscheduler=false] - STARTED
   >   |
   >   +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
   >       [LIBS]
   >       +- sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@fae8daf
   > ```

The above code works fine with Jetty 9.1.5.v20140505 and Java 7 but when fail when I upgrade to Jetty 9.4.1.v20170120 and Java 8.
Browser console report an 404 error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8443/myContext/ws/communication/5/kbui/None' failed: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Did I miss something when upgrade Jetty?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your webContext initialization look like?

Comment: Dump your server (post-startup) and report its tree in your question. `server.dumpStdErr();`

Comment: I modify post to add Server, Webapp context code.

Comment: I post the dump, because size is limited to 30000 chars, I must put placeholders for some content such as jar files, servlets mapping..

Comment: I updated dump with your command server.dumpSteErr() instead of the option in Jetty.xml, and it logs more of websocket. I see a strange line **+~ org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.ServerContainer@6fda53a8 - STOPPED**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your setup, you'll wind up with ...

`wss://localhost:8443/myContext/ws/communication/5/kbui/None`

Your `contextPath` isn't `/context`, its actually `/myContext` in your setup.

You trimmed out the Servlet Mappings section on the dump (that was the important part. heh)

But attempting to manually add the `WSCommunication` Endpoint contained in  `WebAppContext` from outside of the `WebAppClassloader` or the WebApp's ServletContext is probably going to be a problem as well.

You have 3 options:

1. *The JSR356 Automatic Way*

   Setup bytecode scanning and annotation discovery for your `WebAppContext` and let the startup discover and auto-load the `WSCommunication` endpoint.

   Add the following to your `webContext` ...

```java
webContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356",Boolean.TRUE);

webContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
            new AnnotationConfiguration(),
            new WebXmlConfiguration(),
            new WebInfConfiguration(),
            new PlusConfiguration(), 
            new MetaInfConfiguration(),
            new FragmentConfiguration(), 
            new EnvConfiguration()});
```

And add the `jetty-annotations` dependency to your project.

2. *The JSR356 Manual Way*

   Use the `javax.websocket.server.ServerApplicationConfig` to report the `WSCommunication` as being available to be added from within the webapp's startup.
3. *The Servlet Spec Manual Way*

   This is the easiest approach.
   Create a `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` that adds the `WSCommunication` endpoint to the `ServerContainer`

```java
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        ServerContainer container = (ServerContainer)sce.getServletContext()
                   .getAttribute(ServerContainer.class.getName());

        try
        {
            container.addEndpoint(WSCommunication.class);
        }
        catch (DeploymentException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to add endpoint",e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try the #1 approach and it works like a charm. Thanks so much.

Comment: About how previous code works on 9.1.5, you mean I setup websocket wrong, but 9.1.5 still accept, going to 9.4.1 the Jetty server is more strict then it refuse. Right?

Comment: Another question, in reality, my server may support multiple contexts, all of 3 approaches still work with multiple WebAppContext?

Comment: I tested #1, works with multiple contexts (each context have own WSCommunication websocket connection).