# Jetty upgrade (9.2.24 -> 9.4.10) fails with websocket (UpgradeException)

Tags: websocket, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am in the process of upgrading our jetty from 9.2.24 to 9.4.10, for an app that works extensively with websockets.

I have an existing test (junit) that sets embedded jetty, registers to it rest resource and websocket servlet and then tests to see if they can be accessed.

The test works **perfectly well** when jetty is at version 9.2.24. An attempt to move to version 9.4.10 **with the very same code** fails with

```
java.io.IOException: Connect failure
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connect(ClientContainer.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connectToServer(ClientContainer.java:255)   
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.onComplete(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:193)
```

The websocket definition on server side is based o JSR356 spec (i.e. extends *EndPoint*). The websocket client used to access the websocket is also based on the javax.websocket (i.e. *ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().connectToServer(Endpoint instance...)*) - where the websocket container is effectively a jetty one...

The server sets up perfectly. The problem is only when trying to access the websocket. I have debugged and could not find any difference in the way the client initiates and sends the websocket request. In particular the request has a the 'upgrade' header set to 'websocket' as expected.

So I could only assume that the problem is in the way the websocket resource is registered in the embedded jetty. I have debugged the **working** flow (with 9.2.24) and found the most early place where the connection is accepted in jetty (one of the selector threads at AbstractConnection). but from some reason I am not getting to that point for the websocket when working with 9.4.10

I have read several resources and SO question (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524174/websocket-jsr-356-fail-with-jetty-9-4-1)) and could not found anything that will help me with this problem.
I am in a dead end.

Here is the key elements in the relevant code of the server registration (I also have another rest resource along with the websocket one):

```
// web socket
ServletContextHandler wsContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
wsContext.setContextPath("/ws_api");
ServerContainer container = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(servletContextHandler);
container.addEndpoint(new BasicServerEndpointConfig(container.getClient(), endpointClassObject, path)

// rest handler
ServletContextHandler restContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
restContext.setContextPath("/rest_api");
...
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(...);
restContext.addServlet(sh, "/*");

final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{wsContext, restContext, new DefaultHandler()});
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

Help...

**Update** (additional information per Joakim Erdfelt request):

I am at class **HTTPConnection** class, in BP at **onComplete()** method, fetching the request headers from the **_channel._fields** object I get:

[image]

The response object's status is 200 (and not 101 as expected):

[image]

My endpoint object is part of a large inheritance chain. It is full of boilerplate business logic code that I need to remove before I can upload it, but in the root stands the **javax.websocket.Endpont** class, where we implemented only the **onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config)** method. I am not getting to that method when debugging, seems to fail long before...

Comment: You would need to capture the request/response headers to know what's going on.

Comment: Perhaps show your code for both your Endpoint and your Client as well.

Comment: Updated the question with additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request headers looks like this ...

```
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: sMQPm6Cf00itLII3QBb4w==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_144
```

That is an invalid WebSocket Upgrade Request.
The most glaring omission is

```
Connection: upgrade
```

But there's also other fields that a compliant WebSocket Client would never set.

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: You are probably right regarding the connection header. (I even have a basic hunch where do we override it). I missed it. I am not at work now, and will check it first thing when I can, and will update accordingly. 
Do you think that the existence of other headers you mentioned also breaks the code or that it simply doesn't make sense in the context ? (but should not fail)
If indeed this is the problem - does it sounds like something that would work well on 9.2.24 and will FAIL on 9.4.10 ? (because it is the very same client code that I am using with both versions which only fails on 9.4.10)

Comment: lack of `Connection: upgrade` fails WebSocket upgrade in Jetty 7.0.x thru 9.4.x

Comment: Indeed it worked as expected. I see that from some reason my test doesn't override the connection header when I run with 9.2.x - so the problems still remains somewhere inside my code. Jetty works as expected :)
Thanks for the valuable information.